# Class with @Deprecated annotation means that all methods and fields automatically will be deprecated

Tags: java, eclipse, deprecated

Is Anyone knows if the class with `@Deprecated` annotation means that all methods and fields automatically will be deprecated..?

From [JLS 9.6.3.6. @Deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.6)

At lease eclipse is not showing methods  as `Deprecated` for Deprecated class.

Comment: No it only means the type is deprecated, all the methods are left non deprecated

Answer (score 7):

No. If you do

```
@Deprecated
class Old {
     public void foo () {}
}
```

the when you'll reference that class:

> new <del>Old</del>().foo()

only

> <del>Old</del>

will be marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

If say I have annotated the class `VO` with `@Deprecated`:

```
@Deprecated
class VO {
  private String name ;
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Then :

> <del>VO</del> v = new VO(); // warning here

```
v.getName(); // no warning
```

It means the class is deprecated. Hence the use of that type will show warning.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the spec says this:

> A Java compiler must produce a deprecation warning when a type [..] whose declaration is annotated with the annotation @Deprecated is used (i.e. overridden, invoked, or referenced by name), [..]

So **strictly speaking** calling a method on an object of which the type is deprecated is not required to produce a warning (since "overridden" and "invoked" can only reference methods or constructors and the class is not referenced by name). *Declaring* that object, however **must** provide a warning.

However, nothing says that the compiler isn't allowed to provide more warnings. And in my opinion it is reasonable to assume that all methods of a deprecated class should be considered deprecated.

Comment: About the last part: That's exactly what Eclipse does. For showing warnings and errors in the editor Eclipse uses it's own compiler, which produces deprecated warnings on non-deprecated members of deprecated classes.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer  so it means some compile can be produce warning for functions also if Class is marked as Deprecated. Same here in my  opinion it should produced a warning.